# Strange behavior of toolstrip button

Tags: c#

Same code does not function same for toolstrip button as it does for a normal button.

Appl. Details;

A datagridview consist of 6 columns in total.  6th column is a checkbox column to select 2 rows. And after pressing toolstrip bar button, program reads selected rows - [0] cell index values. this happens normally and program actually gets 2 row values when event is coming from normal button, but when event is fired from toolstrip button, list is only populated with 1 element even though 2 rows are selected.

code:

```
private void btnReportPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var checkedRows = from DataGridViewRow r in gridMeasD.Rows
                          where Convert.ToBoolean(r.Cells[5].Value) == true
                          select r; 
       List<string> measIdList = new List<string>(2);           

        foreach (var row in checkedRows)
        {
            measIdList.Add(row.Cells["clm_MeasID"].Value.ToString());
        }

        if (measIdList.Count > 2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please only select 2 different measurements to print out a report !", "Invalid Selection", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        else if(measIdList.Count == 2)
        {
            string val1 = measIdList[0];
            string val2 = measIdList[1];

            if (!((val1[0] == 'F' && val2[0] == 'C') || (val1[0] == 'C' && val2[0] == 'F')))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please only select 2 different measurements to print out a report !", "Invalid Selection", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if ((val1[0] == 'F' && val2[0] == 'C') || (val1[0] == 'C' && val2[0] == 'F'))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Report printing!", "Successful", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            }
            measIdList.Clear();
        }
    }
```

I am looking for an explanation because it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Where is `measIdList` defined? Why aren't you clearing it when `btnReportPrint_Click` enters?

Comment: Your `btnReportPrint_Click` method will crash if `measIdList` contains 0 or 1 items - you need to remove the comment for `//if(measIdList.Count == 2)`.

Comment: It was outside of this event function (before it was in it) but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Have you looked at whether the DGV losing focus to a toolstripbutton is any different to losing it to a normal button/is the second checkmark you have placed somehow "not committed" to whatever the dgv is storing it in? Does calling dgv.EndEdit() as the first line of the event handler change the behavior any?

Comment: @CaiusJard now i added dvg.EndEdit() at the beginning and it is working normally now. Thank you.

Comment: Posted as an answer so it can be marked as solved..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is (and I haven't checked) that clicking on a toolstrip button somehow doesn't cause the DGV to end its editing of the currect cell in the same way that clicking a regular button does, which means a process flow of:

- Click in checkbox within grid; grid is showing checkbox editor component but the value is not yet committed to the underlying cell
- Click toolstrip button; DGV is still editing the cell value and in Cells property it's still the opposite of what is seen
- Scan the Cells for checked values returns only the previously checked Cell, not the current one

Explicitly telling the DGV to end its editing of the current cell, via `dgv.EndEdit()` within the event handler, before the Cells collection is enumerated, should help